# Marker with image and number in google maps api

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using gmap .. I want to put some marker on the map the marker icon is dynamic, I also want a "Number" to be display with the Icon , Is this possible..
My Code is

```
function putMaker(position, title, title_dis, number, icon_img)
{
    if (!isNaN(number))
        var icon = "https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chst=d_bubble_icon_text_small&chld=ski|bb|" + number + "|FFFFFF|000000";
    else
        var icon = null;
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: position,
        map: map,
        icon: icon_img,
        shadow: icon,
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function() {
        infowindow.setContent(title_dis);
        infowindow.open(map, this);
    });
}
```

And Icon is

```
var icon_img = new google.maps.MarkerImage(
        "<?php echo  base_url().'timthumb.php?src='.$url.'&h=32&w=50'; ?>", //url
        new google.maps.Size(50, 32), //size
        new google.maps.Point(0, 0), //origin
        new google.maps.Point(0, 32) //anchor 
        );
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is perfectly possible using the **[markerwithlabel library](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markerwithlabel/1.1.9/docs/examples.html)**. You can modify **[one of the basic examples](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markerwithlabel/1.1.9/examples/lettered.html)** by adding the `icon`parameter (you can add there any of the [standard `google.maps.Marker` options](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?hl=cs&csw=1#MarkerOptions)):

```
var marker = new MarkerWithLabel({
   position: homeLatLng,
   map: map,
   draggable: true,
   raiseOnDrag: true,
   labelContent: "2", // your number
   icon: "img/your_icon.png",
   labelAnchor: new google.maps.Point(3, 30),
   labelClass: "labels", // the CSS class for the label
   labelInBackground: false
 });
```

[image]

### http://jsfiddle.net/Vug7W/