# Google Map API Marker add dynamic lable in Ruby On Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-maps, gmaps4rails

I wan to display many locations of sensors on a map, I need to display all current sensor value on the marker(not on infowindow,user can see data without click marker)

Is not realistic for me to create many different icon and change icon.
Is there a way to display dynamic data on marker? Say display a number label on top of marker. I find one but cant translate it into ruby on rails code.
Here is the link i found for [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20868876/marker-with-image-and-number-in-google-maps-api).
And here is a [link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R0l-7en3dUw&feature=youtu.be) useful for create gmaps on ROR

This is what I have now.Using gem Gmaps4rails.

In app/asssts/gmaptest.js.coffee

```
class CustomMarkerBuilder extends Gmaps.Google.Builders.Marker
create_marker: ->
options = _.extend @marker_options(), @rich_marker_options()
@serviceObject = new RichMarker options

rich_marker_options: ->
marker = document.createElement("div")
marker.setAttribute('class', 'custom_marker_content')
marker.innerHTML = this.args.custom_marker
{ content: marker }

create_infowindow: ->
return null unless _.isString @args.custom_infowindow

boxText = document.createElement("div")
boxText.setAttribute("class", 'custom_infowindow_content')
boxText.innerHTML = @args.custom_infowindow
@infowindow = new InfoBox(@infobox(boxText))

infobox: (boxText)->
content: boxText
pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(-140, 0)
boxStyle:
  width: "280px"
@buildMap=(markers)->
handler = Gmaps.build("Google", builders: { Marker: CustomMarkerBuilder } )
handler.buildMap { internal: id: "custom_builder" }, ->
marker = handler.addMarker
lat:               40.689167
lng:               -74.044444
custom_marker:     "<img src='images/star.jpg' width='30' height='30'> Some text here"
custom_infowindow: "<img src='images/statue.jpg' width='90' height='140'> some test here"

handler.map.centerOn marker
handler.getMap().setZoom(15)
@hash = Gmaps4rails.build_markers(@noiseDevices) do |noiseDevice, marker|
marker.lat noiseDevice.latitude
marker.lng noiseDevice.longitude
end
```

In app/controller/gmaptest_controller.rb

```
@noiseDevices = NoiseDevice.all
@hash = Gmaps4rails.build_markers(@noiseDevices) do |noiseDevice, marker|
marker.lat noiseDevice.latitude
marker.lng noiseDevice.longitude
marker.json({custom_marker: "hi all"})
end
```

In app/view/gmaptest/index.html.erb

```
<script src="//maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3.13&amp;sensor=false&amp;libraries=geometry" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src='//google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markerclustererplus/2.0.14/src/markerclusterer_packed.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
<script src='//google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/richmarker/src/richmarker-compiled.js' type='text/javascript'></script>

<h1>Listing gmaptests</h1>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Latitude</th>
    <th>Longitude</th>
    <th>Address</th>
    <th>Description</th>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>

<% @noiseDevices.each do |noiseDevice| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= noiseDevice.latitude %></td>
    <td><%= noiseDevice.longitude %></td>




  </tr>
<% end %>
</table>

<br />

<%= link_to 'New gmaptest', new_g1test_path %>
<div style='width: 800px;'>
<div id="custom_builder" style='width: 800px; height: 400px;'></div>
 </div>
<div style='width: 800px;'>
  <div id="map" style='width: 800px; height: 400px;'></div>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">

handler = Gmaps.build('Google');
handler.buildMap({ provider: {}, internal: {id: 'map'}}, function(){
markers = handler.addMarkers(<%=raw @hash.to_json %>);
handler.bounds.extendWith(markers);
handler.fitMapToBounds();
});
</script>
```

The problem now is when I try follow video/tutorial and edit the files in view, the whole google map window disappear.one of the causes is add buildMap(<%=raw@hash.to_json%>) ,and other is change the script in view to 
    `<script type="text/javascript">

    var handler = Gmaps.build("Google", builders: { Marker: CustomMarkerBuilder } )
    handler.buildMap({ internal: id: "map" }, function(){
    var markers = handler.addMarkers(<%=raw @hash.to_json %>);
    });
    </script>`

Comment: did you look at http://apneadiving.github.io/ ?

Comment: @apneadiving oh!thank you.I just find custom_marker may meet my need.

Comment: @apneadiving I try copy code from custom marker to myfile.js.coffee,but really dont know what to do next.the marker stay the same

Comment: what do you have exactly?

Comment: @apneadiving Now I have a ROR project,the link u provide is java script.not sure how to merge with my project.the function is what I need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1:

create a coffee file, name it `gmaps4rails_builder.coffee`:

```
class @CustomMarkerBuilder extends Gmaps.Google.Builders.Marker
  create_marker: ->
    options = _.extend @marker_options(), @rich_marker_options()
    @serviceObject = new RichMarker options

  rich_marker_options: ->
    marker = document.createElement("div")
    marker.setAttribute('class', 'custom_marker_content')
    marker.innerHTML = this.args.custom_marker
    { content: marker }
```

Step2:

in your view:

```
<script src='//google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/richmarker/src/richmarker-compiled.js' type='text/javascript'></script>

<script type="text/javascript">  
  var handler = Gmaps.build("Google", builders: { Marker: CustomMarkerBuilder } )
  handler.buildMap({ internal: id: "map" }, function(){
    var markers = handler.addMarkers(<%=raw @hash.to_json %>);
  });
</script>
```

Step3:

In your controller:

```
@hash = Gmaps4rails.build_markers(@noiseDevices) do |noiseDevice, marker|
  marker.lat noiseDevice.latitude
  marker.lng noiseDevice.longitude
  marker.json({
    custom_marker: "marker html here"
  })
end
```

Comment: I read your [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R0l-7en3dUw&feature=youtu.be) again, the [file](http://apneadiving.github.io/) from gmaps4rails coffee script  is to be put on controller's coffee file under app/assets/javascripts/gmaptest.js.coffee .the header file and html file I also follow ur video.The problem is, after I add line  buildMap(<%=raw@hash.to_json%>) in view/gmaptest/index.html.erb  my whole google map window disappear.It happens when I trying to follow your video also.

Comment: can I ask where to put this 'gmaps4rails_builder.coffee' file?is it under app/assets/javascripts ?

Comment: Yes, and ensure you require it in your application.js